# Append Variable Inside Foreach: Azure data factory

Tags: azure, variables, append, azure-data-factory

I am appending variable with a key column inside for each loop for each record processed

first for each for create, the second time for an update, for delete.(sequentially)

First, two-time(inside two for each) variables appends with correct id, but inside third for each the variable append value with \n value \n\n.

Any idea why these \n are appending with value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC5zT.png)
[image]

after third for each
[image]

Comment: Are you using a String variable?  You probably want to use an Array.  This will give the behaviour you expect.  You can then handle it with For Each activity or the built-in array functions like take, last, skip etc

Comment: Hi, Can you please share the expression you are passing in the append?

Comment: NO, I am using the Array itself. Expression is just Id like, 1b877c3b-f43f-4841-9826-849ba63b42c3

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be some escape characters in your data for this ID value.

You can remove the escape character using replace().

Example:

[image]

Option1: To replace the escape character, replace enter (press enter instead of \n) and replace it with ‘’.

```
@replace(variables('id'),'
','')
```

[image]

Option2: Edit the JSON code of the pipeline (which is right side in the pipeline with brackets {}) and replace ‘\n’ with ‘’.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is also a solution but my issue was something else that I resolved. In the expression builder, I was starting my expression after the next line, so the value came up with \n.